# Is it bad to have a stand alone firewall that disables the native system firewall?

Tags: windows-7, windows, security, firewall

I've heard claims that firewalls such as the one that comes with Avast are better than others that disable the system firewall. Is it correct that it could lead to problems disabling a firewall built into the OS? I heard the Windows firewall is built into the TCP/IP stack and can't be disabled fully.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the windows firewall components (services, hooks, etc.) are usually used by the 3rd party firewalls (When they disable the windows built-in firewall, they take control over the underlying components).

I can't see any potential problems by disabling the built-in firewall, but having two active firewalls seems quite problematic to me (same as having two Anti-virus apps).

BTW, I think there's no point in installing a 3rd party firewall at all, unless they support some advanced IDS/IPS functions (which the Windows built-in firewall doesn't).
For any other purpose the built-in firewall in Win7 is quite easy to use and straight-forward.